# How to send 14 emails/second from mailster plugin in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, newsletter

We are working on a project that requires sending the newsletter every day to a number of subscribers. For the transmitter (AMAZON SES) SMTP which allows to have a sending rate of 14mails / s. Unfortunately this rate is blocked only 2mails / s.

my questions is :

1: when you smtp or api web of SES What is the control of the speed of sending newsletters ? 
NB: i use wordpress and mailster plugin to send newsletter and my website is in shared server
2: how can increase speed limit ?

Comment: build your email as a batch and send only one email to the subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request an [increase of your SES sending limits](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/extendedaccessrequest/).
Just follow the link above and fill your request.
This is a standard procedure, AWS should approve it quickly.

Comment: Thank u for the answer 

SES Has increased my limite after my request to 250000 mail/day and Max Send Rate:14 emails/second **BUT** I still send just 2 emails/second in my website wordpress using MAILSTER plugin . 

i don't know if SES WEB API control the sending speed or my shard speed

Comment: Maybe an update of Mailster's setting is needed. Have you tried this: https://kb.mailster.co/how-can-i-increase-the-sending-speed/

Comment: Hey, yes i change the cron interval and Increase the “numbers of mails sent at once" still the same probleme. Does the transmission speed is controlled by the server that contains the site although I use SES AMAZON to send newsletter.

Comment: 14 emails/second --> This doesn't mean you can send emails with multiple recipient and count it as 1 email, 2 emails/second --> Are you adding multiple recipients in these emails or do you see rate limiting errors ?

Comment: For such a volume, you should probably consider using a service like Mailchimp.

Comment: For now, we have 20.000 verified subscribers that we wish to send them the newsletters for each one 6 newsletter in 5 day of week and the number is increasing every day .
the problem is i need for that more than 24h
Is there a relation between the shared server where the website is located  and SES **Which affects the transmission speed** ?

Comment: @HassaniMohamed probably not.